# When Adding Parameter in the Where Clause it Returns Zero rows

Tags: sql-server

```
Create table TmpEmp(Empcode int,Ename nvarchar(50),department nvarchar(50))

Insert into TmpEmp values(1001,'Scott','IT')
Insert into TmpEmp values(1002,'Peter','IT')
Insert into TmpEmp values(1003,'Ricky','HR')

select * from TmpEmp

Declare @Department nvarchar(50)
Set @Department = '''IT'',''HR'''
--Set @Department = 'ALL'
--print @Department
select * from TMPEMP where (1=1)
and Department in 
(case @Department when 'ALL' then Department else @Department End )
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: When @Department Parameter has values 'IT','HR'  it returns no rows can you help?

Comment: Set @Department = '''IT'',''HR'' is not an array of items

Answer (score 0):

First of all your @Department variable has no string `ALL`

```
Set @Department = '''IT'',''HR'''
```

Second, it's comma separated strings; so you just can't use `=` operator. rather you will have to use `LIKE` operator. If I just change your posted code as below; result will be returned

```
Declare @Department nvarchar(50);
Set @Department = '''IT'',''ALL''';

select * from TMPEMP where (1=1)
and Department in 
(case when @Department like '%ALL%' then Department else @Department End )
```

Change your query to use `IN` operator. See this fiddle demo http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/4d9c9/20

```
select * from TMPEMP 
where Department in (case when @Department not in ('ALL')
 then Department else @Department End )
```

Comment: What If @Department ='''IT''' It doesnt return any row?

Comment: @user3071287, Yes it will return row but you can't use a comma separated list. rather you will have to store single value.

Comment: How to Work with Comma seperated List then? As From UI its a multiselect dropdown it returns value with comma seperated only.     Set @Department = '''IT'',''HR''' Any solution for this Rahul?